# Did Nietzsche say "Wherever is the crowd is a common denominator of stench"?

Tags: nietzsche, translation

I found very few occurrences of that quote attributed to Nietzsche: "Wherever is the crowd is a common denominator of stench".

I suspect this to be an Internet false positive, namely a false quote, because I've never found that one elsewhere.

Does anyone here have a clue? I'm trying to assess if it's genuine (in English, translated from German), and find it in French/

Comment: Yes, Nietzsche has been translated. E stato tradotto, no ? German>English.

Comment: Excellent. I suspect the original quote is still dubious, possibly adapted from the one you found.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Could you give some examples of pages where this quote is attributed to Nietzsche? References are important.

Answer (score 4):

Possible source : [Beyond Good and Evil](http://www.lexido.com/EBOOK_TEXTS/BEYOND_GOOD_AND_EVIL_.aspx?S=3&WSD_HL=368#WSD_HL) (1886), **Chapter 2 The Free Spirit**, §30:

> "Books for the general reader are always ill-smelling books, the odour of paltry people clings to them. Where the populace eat and drink, and even where they reverence, it is accustomed to stink. One should not go into churches if one wishes to breathe pure air."

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough. It certainly confirms initial quote was probably a mish-mash.